# Getting same session object

Tags: java, hibernate, session

In simple hibernate program i am getting detail of Employee table by using following code. :-
**Employee employee = (Employee) session.get(Employee.class, new Integer(6));**
and same time i print the information in console 
System.out.println("Name : -"+employee.getName() + "Address :- " + employee.getAddress());

Now paused the execution for 15000 ms.  **Thread.sleep(15000);**
during this time i go through database and manually change the details of employee table.
when **15000ms completed** , then i clear session cache and again try to fetch same record but i'm getting same object having same information  . whatever information change during sleep time would not be reflected.

below is the program

Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

```
configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
ServiceRegistry registry = (ServiceRegistry) builder.buildServiceRegistry();
builder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
ServiceRegistry registry = (ServiceRegistry) builder.buildServiceRegistry();
factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(registry);

Session session = factory.openSession();
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

Employee employee = (Employee) session.get(Employee.class, new Integer(6));
System.out.println("Name : -" + employee.getName() + "Address :- " + employee.getAddress());

Thread.sleep(15000);
//now i made change in database going through the mysql workbench and manually change the details of emp id 6.

System.out.println(" cache remove");
session.evict(employee);
session.flush();

Employee employee1 = (Employee) session.get(Employee.class, new Integer(6));
System.out.println("Name : -" + employee1.getName() + "Address :- " + employee1.getAddress());
printEmp(employee);
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

Comment: is session.evict(employee2); just a typo?

Answer (score 0):

first ensure that your manual db changes are getting reflected(commited) in db itself as you have already started a transaction.

Check your database isolation level. I think your program is behaving as per it should be.

Also you can try to use show sql option for debugging.